# Safari Print Media Queries not matching other browsers / cutting off

Tags: css, printing, safari, media-queries

I have a web app that looks fine when rendered in Safari but the print media queries are not being respected by the browser.  In Chrome the entire printable area looks fine, however in Safari it appears to be only some variation of visible content.

When scrolling down on the page the header or top area is cut off, when printing higher on the page the bottom is cut off.

I've tried the following for the print media queries (with no effect) -

1. Setting a `min-height`
2. Setting any variation of a `height` value on the container
3. Zooming out and printing
4. Changing resolution / scale

Nothing appears to have any effect at all.

Unlike Chrome, I can't find a way to debug why it is happening nor a way to debug the print styles themselves.

Note - I am using Bootstrap for styles so there are containers, rows, spans, etc... but even removing them completely and everything being on it's own line makes no difference, the same "height" of the content is shown on print.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle as an example?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately jsfiddle wasn't able to reproduce and I gave up when asking.  Then when going back and trying to create a repro I figured out why.  When printing in Chrome it accounted for the fact that I wasn't just trying to print the body but anything visible, Safari doesn't account for the same.  If you put together an answer detailing that I'll gladly award the bounty.  Trick is to use a modal or dialog for print content so that it doesn't affect the overall height of body.

Comment: @Dekel that was at you

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem (and without viewing your html it will be hard to help). Note that if you are using the `rel` tag it's important to have the `print` media query appear **after** the other media queries. If you are not using the `rel` tag, but have inline `style` tag - please add some code (it can be a jsfiddle that "work" only when using as complete page and not inside the jsfiddle structure) so we can try to reproduce.

Comment: @PWKad Since Safari is strict about syntax. Check out your all open and closing `{}` brackets of other media queries. It might be a issue.

Comment: As mentioned above the issue was with a bootstrap dialog modal being taller than the body and safari wasnt taking that into consideration just printing the body height

Comment: Can you give us a code snippet?

Comment: See if this can help: http://lawrencenaman.com/optimisation/print-media-queries-not-working/

Comment: As I mentioned before, anyone that reposts my answer can have the bounty but you've only got an hour left so...

Answer (score 1):

I've had many issues with cross browser print media queries in the past. What helps a lot with regulating the visual is setting a fixed page size and html/body.

For instance:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: 1600px;
    }

    body,
    html {
        width: 1600px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case setting body to it's original A4 width -> `width: 210mm` and `height: 100%` fixed the problem.

I've been working with modified version of **PDFJS** viewer from **PrimeFaces**
and here is a snippet that did the trick in Safari:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 210mm; // A4 Paper width
    height: 100%;
}
```

*note:* The issue was in incorrect pdf document scaling while previewing and then printing docs. FF and Chrome were fine.

Hope it helps somebody, who uses PDFJS extension from PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 0):

I've not gotten any answers on here after pointing out the issue in the comments above and mentioning it was a free bounty.  Unfortunately I'd love to give the bounty away so anyone that reposts this before bounty expires can have it -

The issue was that the application I am using is a JavaScript app that runs and creates the body of the page that was only about 400px tall.  After the body is rendered there is a separate bootstrap modal dialog that was being shown with the content to print and all of the CSS was good and media queries were good but the modals' content was set to larger than the body.

Upon inspection it seems that Safari (and probably other browsers) weren't taking in to account the dialogs height when calculating the height of the body.

Chrome and Firefox were fine with this because it printed all visible content but in Safari it only prints content that is as tall as the body, which in this case was about 30% of the modal.  By manually triggering the body to be `min-height: 1200px;` it resolved the issue since that was the maximum possible height of the Bootstrap Modal dialog's content.