# Safari media-queries print not using height 100% correctly

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I'm using printing media queries for an app that is working fine on Chrome/Edge/Firefox but is failing on Safari. I'm using  height 100% in order to make it fill the printing page, on safari it seems to be using the percentages as a percentage of the element itself. I have put simplified code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>print test</title>
</head>
<style>
    .big{
        border:5px solid black;
    }
    @media print {
        .breaker{
            page-break-before: always;
        }
        .big{
            display:block;
            position:  relative;
            height:100%;
        }
    }
</style>
<body>
    <svg class = "big" width="700px" height="1000px"></svg>
    <div class = "breaker"></div>
    <svg class = "big" width="700px" height="1000px"></svg>
    <div class = "breaker"></div>
    <svg class = "big" width="700px" height="1000px"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting page's size property to A4 ( `@page { size: A4; }` ) and body to the width of A4 size. ( `body { width: 210mm; }` ). Safari pays attention on that values.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=print) Safari doesn't support `@page` and `page-after-break`

This is a similar question on StackOverflow -
 [Safari Print Media Queries not matching other browsers / cutting off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670163/safari-print-media-queries-not-matching-other-browsers-cutting-off)

Try setting a specific size for the body and HTML.