# My page shows up blank when printed in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, macos, printing, safari

[My page](https://cadehunter.github.io/Scorekeeper) uses an @print media query, and when printing in Chrome, Safari on iOS, and Edge, it works properly and shows the page with the stylesheet correctly applied when printing. In macOS Safari, however, the print preview is blank when the page is printed.

When triggering the print stylesheet manually in the Web Inspector, the page displays properly, but it does not do so in the print preview.

(I should add that I tested with Safari on Catalina and Big Sur Developer Beta, both with Safari 14.0)

Comment: Please do add some snippets of your code that is related to your issue. You don't have to put the entire code here. Just add your related CSS snippets and probably a short version of your html template that should still work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Can I use `print`?](https://caniuse.com/?search=print), Safari 14 is not supported.

You might find this useful:

> Try setting page's size property to **A4** ( `@page { size: A4; }` ) and body to the width of A4 size. ( `body { width: 210mm; }` ). Safari pays attention on that values.

- taken from [Lefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3298024/lefan)'s comment on [Safari media-queries print not using height 100% correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44925902/2678218)

Also have the same answer from the same guy from here: [Safari Print Media Queries not matching other browsers / cutting off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533935/2678218)